# Multiset of Hamming distances for a tour of all subsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, hamming-distance, gray-codes

Consider a list of all the subsets of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, in any order.  Using binary notation, one such list for $n=3$ is
$$ 010, 100, 110, 011, 000, 111, 001, 101. $$
Now consider the Hamming distance between consecutive subsets in the list. In this example: $$2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1.$$ Now forget the order of the list of distances and write it as a multiset:
$$\{\!\{ 1,1,2,2,2,3 \}\!\}.$$
The question is: **What multisets are possible?**

Obviously there must be $2^n-1$ elements, each an element of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

A famous case is the minimum-change Gray code that gives $\{\!\{1,1,1,1,1,1,1\}\!\}$. Some multisets are impossible, such as $\{\!\{2,2,2,2,2,2,2\}\!\}$. $\{\!\{1,1,1,3,3,3,3\}\!\}$ is possible but $\{\!\{1,1,3,3,3,3,3\}\!\}$ is not.

Is there at least a conjecture?

Comment: One necessary condition is that the sum of the multiset elements cannot exceed $n2^n - 2^{n-1} - n + 1$. The proof can be found in Math StackExchange ["Anti-Gray codes" that maximize the number of bits that change at each step](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/315544/573047). In the example $\{\{1,1,3,3,3,3,3\}\}$, the sum is $17 \lt 18$, however the multiset is not possible.

Comment: @BillyJoe That table concerns distances between each pair of codewords, not only the distances between consecutive codewords in an ordered list. So it is not easy to extract useful information about my problem. Please respond if you disagree.